# PATCH verb in rest api with nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, express, request, sequelize.js

What is the correct form of implement the PATCH verb in a rest api using nodejs express ?
PATCH is used when you want to update a specific field, but Im getting confused cause idk how to implement it server-side. how can the server knows wich field it's gonna be updated ?
How'd be the html request and how nodejs process that request ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement them from scratch using Express’ `app.patch(callback)`. The callback is called with `req` and `res` arguments, and you can use `req.body` to do whatever you want.